# visual studio 2010 include file can 'see' but cannot compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include-path

I'm sure there is a really simple solution to this.

I'm trying to include a header file.  I have added the include directory.  when I include with quotes the new feature in vs2010 now shows me that it can 'see' the file I want to include and the tool tip references it in the correct directory.

however I get a red underscore under the #include indicating there is a problem and the project won't build because it cannot include the file.

I can build by adding the full relative path but this is a bit messy.

so in summary

```
#include "myfile.h"  FAILS
#include "../../includes/myfile.h" WORKS
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the absolute path of your file and what are your include directories?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `../../includes` in the following field:

Project Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

For more details visit the appropriate [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: There is not enough information to help you further. Try to create a minimal project that exhibits faulty behavior. After that make this minimal project more and more similar to original project. At one point you will find a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
#include "myfile.h"
```

fails, but

```
#include "../../includes/myfile.h"
```

works, that means you *don't* have the include directories in your path. Say you have your structure like this:

```
/project
   /src
      myfile.cpp   -> myfile.h included here
   /include
      /dir1
          myfile.h
```

You need to add to your include directories `./include/dir1/`, not just `./project` or `./include`.

Using `<...>` instead of `"..."` just tells the compiler to first look in the system include directories first, so that wouldn't be of much help. Answers stating this are wrong. Usually, you would use `<...>` for headers like `string` or `vector` and `"..."` type includes for your own headers.

Comment: I had added the include dirs.